# Find all $x$ for that $x^2 + (x+1)^2$ is a square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to find all natural $x$ for that $x^2 + (x+1)^2$ is a perfect square?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Suppose $x^2 + (x+1)^2 = y^2$. We can rewrite it as $(2x+1)^2 + 1 = 2y^2$ or $(2x+1)^2 - 2y^2 = -1$.

If $z=2x+1$ then we have $z^2 - 2y^2 = -1$. This is [Pell's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell_equation).
Wikipedia article shows how to solve it.

Comment: In particular, because the smallest solution of z²-2y²=-1 is (1,1), all solutions are given by writing (1+√2)^n = z + y√2, for odd n. For instance (1+√2)³ = (7+5√2). So solutions (z,y) are (1,1), (7,5), (41,29), (239,169), (1393,985) and so on, corresponding to x = 0, 3, 20, 119, 696, …

Answer (score 0):

Note that these squares form a primitive Pythagorean Triplet, so there exist integers $p$ and $q$ such that $n = p^2 - q^2$ and $n+1 = 2pq$ (or the other way around). Thus, $p^2 - q^2 = 2pq \pm 1 \implies (p-q)^2 + 2q^2 = \pm 1$.

Let $u=p-q$, and $v=q$, so we have the Pell equations $u^2 - 2v^2 = 1$ and $u^2 - 2v^2 = -1$.

**Part 1:** $u^2 - 2v^2 = 1$

The fundamental solution of this can be observed as being $(3, 2)$. Thus, using the recursive formula $(u_{n+1}, v_{n+1}) = (u_0  u_n + D v_0 v_n, u_0 v_n + v_0 u_n)$, we get the following solutions: $(3, 2), (17, 12), (99, 49), \ldots$. These give the respective values for $(p,q)$: $(5, 2), (29, 12), (148, 49), \ldots$, which respectively give these values for $n$: $n=20, 696, 7252, \ldots$. Thus, all satisfying $n<200$ in this case is only $n=20$.

**Part 2:** $u^2 - 2v^2 = -1$

The fundamental solution for this can be observed as being $(1, 1)$. Thus, using the recursive formula $(u_{n+1}, v_{n+1}) = (u'_0  u_n + D v'_0 v_n, u'_0 v_n + v'_0 u_n)$, where $(u'_0, v'_0)$ is the fundamental solution of $u^2 - 2v^2 = 1$, we get the following solutions: $(1, 1), (7, 5), (41, 29), \ldots$. These give the respective values for $(p,q)$: $(2, 1), (12, 5), (70, 29), \ldots$, which respectively give these values for $n$: $n=3, 119, 4059, \ldots$. Thus, all satisfying $n<200$ in this case are $n=3, 119$.

Thus, we have all satisfying values of $n$ to be $3, 20, 119$.

---

I believe another solution can be attained by Vieta Root Jumping for $(p, q)$, as can be noticed by the combinations $(2, 1), (5, 2), (12, 5), (29, 12), (70, 29), \ldots$.